# SQL: LEFT OUTER JOIN duplicates some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have 2 lists:

1)

```
FG       FG lot
12043267 6105552268 
12043267 6109552268  
12043267 6110552268  
12043267 6111552268
```

2)

```
item     item lot
43626551 610457472H 
43626551 610557472H 
43626551 610957471H 
43626551 610957472H 
43626551 611057472H 
43626551 611157471H 
43626551 611157472H
```

What ***should*** happen:

```
FG       FG lot      item lot    item
12043267 6105552268  610557472H  43626551 
12043267 6109552268  610957471H  43626551 
12043267 6110552268  611057472H  43626551 
12043267 6111552268  611157471H  43626551
```

The general idea: check to see if all the FG lots have a corresponding item lot.

The tricky part is that I need to look at the first 4 digits for comparison and then only consider if there is one corresponding item lot. That is, I don't care if there are 3, 4, 5, 99 item lots on the right side, so long as there is at least 1 corresponding item lot.

**My code:**

```
DECLARE @FG NVARCHAR(30) = '12043267'
DECLARE @proddate datetime = '6/8/2016'
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT DISTINCT

    t.item,
    t.lot,
    candylots.lot,
    candylots.item

FROM

    ISW_LPTrans AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN

        (SELECT TOP 1

        --t.lp_num,
        t.item,
        t.lot

        FROM

            ISW_LPTrans AS t
            INNER JOIN item AS i on i.item = t.item

        WHERE

            i.product_code = 'RM-Candy' AND
            t.trans_date = '6/8/2016' AND
            t.trans_type = 'I' AND
            t.ref_num IN

                (

                    SELECT

                        j.job

                    FROM

                        job AS j

                    WHERE

                        j.item = '12043267' AND
                        j.job_date = '6/6/2016'

                )

            AND t.ref_line_suf IN

                (

                    SELECT

                        j.suffix

                    FROM

                        job AS j

                    WHERE

                        j.item = '12043267' AND
                        j.job_date = '6/6/2016'     

                ) 

        GROUP BY

            t.item,
            t.lot

        ) AS candylots ON LEFT(candylots.lot, 4) = LEFT(t.lot, 4)

WHERE

    t.ref_num = 'N000016174' AND
    t.ref_line_suf = 24 AND
    t.trans_type = 'F' AND
    t.item = '12043267' AND
    t.trans_date = '6/8/2016'

/*GROUP BY

    t.item,
    t.lot,
    candylots.lot,
    candylots.item*/
```

**What the code does:**

```
FG       FG lot      item lot  item
12043267 6105552268  null      null 
12043267 6109552268  null      null 
12043267 6110552268  null      null 
12043267 6111552268  null      null
```

Clearly there is something wrong. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

---

Update:

I tried only `SELECTING` the first four digits of both lists *at the end* and it works, but ideally I'd like to be able to show both lots completely written out.

```
DECLARE @FG NVARCHAR(30) = '12043267'
DECLARE @proddate datetime = '6/8/2016'
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT DISTINCT

    t.item,
    LEFT(t.lot,4) AS FG_lots,
    candylot.candy_lots,
    candylot.item

FROM

    ISW_LPTrans AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN

        (SELECT

            --t.lp_num,
            t.item,
            LEFT(t.lot,4) AS candy_lots

            FROM

                ISW_LPTrans AS t
                INNER JOIN item AS i on i.item = t.item

            WHERE

                i.product_code = 'RM-Candy' AND
                t.trans_date = '6/8/2016' AND --(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @proddate), @proddate)) AND
                t.trans_type = 'I' AND
                t.ref_num IN

                    (

                        SELECT

                            j.job

                        FROM

                            job AS j

                        WHERE

                            j.item = '12043267' AND
                            j.job_date = '6/6/2016'

                    )

                AND t.ref_line_suf IN

                    (

                        SELECT

                            j.suffix

                        FROM

                            job AS j

                        WHERE

                            j.item = '12043267' AND
                            j.job_date = '6/6/2016'     

                    ) 

            GROUP BY

                t.item,
                t.lot

            ) AS candylot ON candylot.candy_lots = LEFT(t.lot, 4)

WHERE

    t.ref_num = 'N000016174' AND
    t.ref_line_suf = 24 AND
    t.trans_type = 'F' AND
    t.item = '12043267' AND
    t.trans_date = '6/8/2016'
```

The correct, but not yet ideal, result:

```
item     FG_lots  candy_lots  item1
12043267 6105     6105        43626551 
12043267 6109     6109        43626551 
12043267 6110     6110        43626551 
12043267 6111     6111        43626551
```

Comment: can you show some examples of what is happening that shouldn't

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Just added it.

Comment: What should the results look like? That is, if there's more than 1 "item lot", what is displayed?

Comment: my guess is that there are no items where the FG_lot's first four characters match the item lot's first four characters for that date and item number

Comment: @PhilipKelley the first `item lot` should be displayed. Or the last, it doesn't matter. I just want to see that any 1 `item lot` satisfies a unique `FG lot`.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus There are. The 2 lists that I mention at the beginning come from running the superquery and the subquery separately. I now need to combine them and show them side by side.

Comment: If your first 4 digits are not unique in FG Lot, you will have duplicates

Comment: why don't you break your 2  tables down first a little so it becomes easy to operate on, create 2 tables but instead of having the full FG lot and item lot have the first 4 numbers, then rebuild again using distinct on those values to remove duplicates, then it should be very easy to left join them together.........

Comment: @PaulS that's basically what I ended up doing. It's not as nice as displaying the full lots for both sides, but it `technically` gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Is it need to be something like this?

```
SELECT t.item, t.lot, i.FG, i.[FG lot]
FROM ISW_LPTrans as t
LEFT JOIN item as i
ON LEFT(i.[FG lot],4) = LEFT(t.lot,4);
```

Or it is too simple?

Comment: It definitely needs to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because I need to see when there is no `item lot` for a given `FG lot`.

Comment: Besides that, this answer resembles my answer and it doesn't work :/